# How to calculate the traffic intensity of an access link?

Tags: telecommunication, network-traffic

I am a computer science student and in my telecommunications course, we were asked a question that I can't solve. Here is the statement:

Either the local network below that accesses the Internet via a 20 Mbps access link.
All local network clients generate an average of 200 requests per second. Each request corresponds to an average of 100,000 bits. It is assumed that the average RTT of the access router to any web server is 8 seconds and that the local network capacity is 100 Mbps.

How intense is the traffic on the access link?

I can't find a formula that could help me. Could I have at least one clue to move forward?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it by using this formula:

(L*a)/R

or

(arrival rate of bite)/(service rate of bits)

Hope this helps you